# returning a specific type in Python

Tags: python

The quick version: 
I'm trying to figure out how to pass either a list or tuple from a function in one script, to a function in another script. The issue I run into, is that it always becomes a NoneObjectType in the second script, and then I can't do anything with it other than print it out as a long string.

The long version:
I use a 3d program called Poser, that allows the use of Python to auto mate tasks. Because of this I made a nice little script called SelectMultiple that gives me a nice wxPython window were I can choose the items I want to modify. Because I can see using this over and over, I wanted it to be it's own script.

Here is the function I'm calling from SelectMultiple:

```
def MyApp():
    title = "Select from list"
    # Make the selection window pop up
    mydialog = userInput(title, lst)
    popupwindow = mydialog.ShowModal()

    # If the user cancels win = 0
    if popupwindow == wx.ID_CANCEL:
        print "User canceled"
        return

    # Get the selected actors
    selected = mydialog.GetSelectedActors()

    # We are finished with the dialog
    mydialog.Destroy()

    return lst(selected)
```

by default **selected** is a tuple, as you can see I tried casting it as a list before returning it, but it doesn't show up that way in my other script. The file does import, and I can print it and get a string that shows the content, but it's always NoneType and I can't do much with it. Here's the script I'm calling from:

```
import poser
import os

scene = poser.Scene()

pathname = os.path.split(poser.AppLocation())[0]
pathname = os.path.join(pathname, 'Runtime', 'Python', 'poserScripts', 'ScriptsMenu', 'GadgetGirl')
sys.path.append(pathname)

try:
    import SelectMultiple
except:
    print "Could not import SelectMultiple script"

    def ChoiceWindow():
        title = "SuperFly Node Fixer"
        message = "Choose the operation to preform"
        list_of_operations = ["Delete Node", "Detach Node", "Re-Link Node"]

        drop_down_window = poser.DialogSimple.AskMenu(title, message, list_of_operations)
        return drop_down_window


    def Controller():
       script_to_run = ChoiceWindow()
       #Need to call multiple so that we can know on what figures
       list_of_figures = SelectMultiple.MyApp()
       print type(list_of_figures)

Controller()
```

So yeah, how do I get something other than a NoneType back.

Comment: Did you intend to type `list(selected)` instead of `lst(selected)` by chance? If intended, you need to also show a minimum example of `mydialog.GetSelectedActors()`

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `return lst(selected)` is even being executed? if your script enters that `if popupwindow == wx.ID_CANCEL:` conditional, then `return` will execute and the return value will be `None`.

Comment: Do you mean `lst` and not `list`? Try printing out the value before you return it. Sounds like the issue is in the object returned by `userInput`.

Comment: so yeah, I did mean list instead of lst. And the problem may now be that my list is empty, because it is returning before I'm ready for it to. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

So I created my own issue with a typo. After I discovered that **selected** wasn't a list but a tuple, I mistyped the list cast as lst and then couldn't figure out why it wasn't a list. Thanks for the help

Answer (score -2):

Loop thru the `selected` tuple and add the items into a list.

```
l = list()    
for item in selected:
    l.append(item)
    return l
```

Also I'm not sure what version of Python you're using but the cast for list is `list()` not `lst()`